# Baire's theorem and a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

The following problem is definitely connected with a creative use of Baire's category theorem, but I didn't grasp the connection yet.

We have $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ which is countable and a family of closed, boundary sets $F_k\subset\mathbb{R}$. What needs to be shown is that there exists $c\in\mathbb{R}^n$ that for every $a\in A$ , $d_e(c,a)\notin\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}F_k$.

What do you propose?

Comment: When you say *closed boundary set*, do you mean *closed nowhere dense set*, i.e., *closed set with empty interior*?

Comment: Yep. Closed with empty interior, so that Baire's theorem is applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: For $a\in A$ and $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $H(a,k)=\{x\in\Bbb R^n:d_e(a,x)\in F_k\}$. Show that $H(a,k)$ is closed and nowhere dense in $\Bbb R^n$. Then note that $\{H(a,k):a\in A\text{ and }k\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is countable.

Comment: Ok, I've slept with it and I think I know how to prove it is closed -- as a continuous preimage of a closed set $d^{-1}(F_k)$. But I have absolutely no idea why would it also be nowhere dense...

Comment: Or I don't know how to properly show that. What I'm thinking about is that for $d: \{a\}\times\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R},\ d^{-1}(d(a,x))$ is a boundary of a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ <-> it is a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ minus its' interior. So it is nowhere dense. Am I correct?

Comment: @Jules: That shows that each $H(a,k)$ is the union of boundaries of closed balls, but not that $H(a,k)$ is necessarily nowhere dense. Suppose that $H(a,k)$ contained some non-empty open set $U$. Pick a point $x\in U$, and look at the closed infinite ray $R$ from $a$ through $x$. That ray is isometric to $[0,\to)$ by the map $y\mapsto d(a,y)$. That map takes $H(a,k)$ to $F_k$ and $R\cap U$ to a non-empty open subset of $F_k$, which is a contradiction.